# ошибка при установке Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

ОС Ubuntu 16.04, при создании проекта Django в PyCarm, выходит ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите решение.

Answer (score 3):

[Тут](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240) обсуждалась данная проблема и её решение в необходимости обновить pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

или:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```